# Adding names to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

```html
<li><form name="project5" id="partTwo" onSubmit="return project5Part2();" >
    <label for="userInput">name:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="userInput"/>
    <input type="submit" />
 </form></li>
</ul>

  

  
<div id="outputDiv" class="output"  >
<p id="numberName"></p>
 <table id="outputTable"></table>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    project5Part2();
</script>
```

```js
// global variable
var userEnteredName = [];
function addInput() {
   var input;
   input = document.getElementById("userInput");
   userEnteredName.push(input.value);      
}
function printToTable() {
    var outputTable;
    outputTable = document.getElementById("outputTable");
    var numbersOfName;
    numbersOfName = document.getElementById("numberName");
    numbersOfName.innerHTML = "numbers of name:" + userEnteredName.length;
    outputTable.innerHTML = "<th>" + "Name" + "</th>";
    for(index = 0; index < userEnteredName.length; index++) {
        outputTable.innerHTML +="<tr><td>" + userEnteredName[index] + "</td></tr>";
    }
}
   /*
    This is the JavaScript code for 
    "Name Entry" 
    File: /unit5/project/project5Part2.html.
 The purpose of this function is to 
*/
function project5Part2() {
    addInput();
    printToTable();
    return false;
}
```

The img is what i got from the code to the webpage.

There is no value but the arrar.length is already 
i need that to be 0 and start counting as i input value into the textbox and push its way through it

[image]

Comment: where do you call the functions?

Comment: sorry, its really messy.

Comment: please add the addition to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok notice how you run your function `project5Part2()` as soon as your page loads, it then invokes: `addInput()`. The problem you have is that `addInput` doesn't check if input is empty, and adds `""` to your global array *`userEnteredName`*.

Your resulting array is of size 1 and looks like `[""]`.

#### Quick Fix is this:

```js
function addInput() {
  var val = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  // Check if value exists and is of a non-zero length, then push to array 
  val && userEnteredName.push(val);
}
```

Now your `addInput` function will only store non-empty strings (ie. when something is actually typed into the input box)

Make sense?

#### EDIT - Adding Clear Button as well:

New changes to HTML:

```js
function clearForm() {
    document.getElementById("userInput").value = ""
    userEnteredName = []
}
```

```html
<li><form name="project5" id="partTwo" onSubmit="return project5Part2();" >
    <label for="userInput">name:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="userInput"/>
    <input type="submit" />
 </form><button onclick="clearForm()">Clear</button></li>
</ul>

  

  
<div id="outputDiv" class="output"  >
<p id="numberName"></p>
 <table id="outputTable"></table>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    project5Part2();
</script>
```

Comment: it did fix it. thank you so much. also, for some reason, when I refresh the webpage it leave my last input in the table. how can I fix that.

Comment: What do you mean by _"leave my last input in the table"_? Maybe attach a snapshot, or JsFiddle?

Comment: ok lets say I input : today, is , a , good ,day. into the textbox . as I refresh it, "day" is still inside the <td>. My point is that if I can reset everything with out Ctrl + f5

Comment: If you mean on a reload... the browser should technically be removing everything. However, if you want to have a clear button, I can include that in my answer as well.

Comment: that would be helpful.

Comment: Added, Does that work?